# jQuery on change only shows the selected option, remove/disable rest of them

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, select, onchange

Target: From a select dropdown menu, if someone selects an option, disable/remove/hide the rest of the options on that dropdown menu.

Here is the dropdown menu. If someone selects "1", the rest of options (2,3,4) will be removed/disabled/hide:

```
<div class="abc">
  <div class="xyz">
    <select name="pqr" class="selectDropdown">
      <option value='1'>1</option>
      <option value='2'>2</option>
      <option value='3'>3</option>
      <option value='4'>4</option>
    </select>
  </div>
</div>
```

Here is the JavaScript I tried to use:

```
$('.selectDropdown').on('change', function(e) {
    $(this).closest('.abc').children('.xyz').children('option:not(:selected)').prop('disabled', true);
});
```

I know, the JavaScript is faulty here. Where did I make the mistake?

Comment: @jaspher thanks for grammatical suggestion. and everyone who replied, thanks for quick replies.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Keep it simple and use:

```
$('.selectDropdown').on('change', function(e) {
    $(this).children('option:not(:selected)').prop('disabled', true);
});
```

In this context, `$(this)` refers to `.selectDropdown` and the `option` elements are the children.

[**Example Here**](http://jsfiddle.net/a1oLm03b/)

---

..and if you want to remove the unselected children:

```
$('.selectDropdown').on('change', function(e) {
    $(this).children('option:not(:selected)').remove();
});
```

[**Example Here**](http://jsfiddle.net/ngq2mnc5/)

---

The reason your code wasn't working was because the `option` elements are *not* direct children of the `.xyz` element. You would have had to use:

```
$('.selectDropdown').on('change', function(e) {
    $(this).closest('.abc').children('.xyz').children().children('option:not(:selected)').prop('disabled', true);
});
```

(I simply chained another `.children()` method after `.children('.xyz')`..)

Answer (score 2):

You're over complicating it. Once the user has clicked on the select box, you're inside that selector so there's no need to go up to .abc and .xyz.

Here's a fiddle to show it working in action:
http://jsfiddle.net/releaf/ng50zmyo/

```
$('.selectDropdown').on('change', function(e) {
 $(this).find('option:not(:selected)').prop('disabled', true);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

This simplifies things. Since `this` is the `select` no need to traverse up 2 levels and back down to get back to where you started again

```
$('.selectDropdown').on('change', function(e) {
    $(this).children(':not(:selected)').prop('disabled', true);
});
```

if remove is preferred swap out `prop()` for `remove()`

```js
$('.selectDropdown').on('change', function(e) {
    $(this).children(':not(:selected)').prop('disabled', true);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="abc">
  <div class="xyz">
    <select name="pqr" class="selectDropdown">
      <option value='1'>1</option>
      <option value='2'>2</option>
      <option value='3'>3</option>
      <option value='4'>4</option>
    </select>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You just select wrong node. `$(this).closest('.abc').children('.xyz')` --> this node's childs point to `select`, which has no child node `option`.

Here you go:

```
$('.selectDropdown').on('change', function(e) {
    $('select[name="pqr"]').children('option:not(:selected)').prop('disabled', true);
});
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tz0rqwvd/)

Comment: why change selectors? that seems confusing when you are targeting the exact same element

Comment: Agreed. There's no reason to query the DOM again here when $(this) is already in context.

Comment: I just want to crarify the correct selector. @crazymoin select the wrong node because he travels up to `'.abc'` and then tralvels down. Instead of solving the "example", why not point out the correct selector?

Comment: but suppose there were 10 of this class in a page. the inner selector may not even be the right one, whereas `this` will always be the element that event occured on and is more readable as well